# Writing a promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to understand Promises and how to write them.

```
const getmsg = ( ) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('Delaying this Message');
    },3000);
}

const displaymsg=()=>{
    console.log('Displayed after getmsg() is executed')
}

const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve(getmsg)
})

promise
    .then(response =>{
        displaymsg();
        console.log(response)
        })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        })
```

I have written two functions getmsg() and displaymsg(). I want the displaymsg() to be executed after getmsg().   According to my understanding i am creating a promise which executes getmsg and then displaymsg() is getting called. But it isn't happening here. Where am i doing wrong.

Comment: You are executing displaymsg() right when your promise is resolved i.e., in .then({})

Comment: if you check you log you'll see that `response` contains the function `getmsg`. At no point in your code are you actually **executing** `getmsg`, you're just passing it around.

Comment: The resolve statement in your promise does nothing but triggers the completion of your promise statement with the data u provide in resolve() in here you are giving it a method signature of getmsg or simply it will take it as undefined if its not defined above. You need to call getmsg() right before displaymsg() inside your promis.then({}) callback

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan [repl](https://repl.it/@TusharRoy/StandardTriflingPresses#index.js) Please let me know how you would do it on this repl.

Comment: const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(true); // u can pass data here
    })

    promise
        .then(response => {
            getmsg();
            displaymsg();
            console.log(response)
        })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
     })

Comment: I'm unable to format it can you edit this comment

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan thank you for your response but it first executes displaymsg and then getmsg after a delay. try this [repl](https://repl.it/join/ioeshcfk-tusharroy)

Comment: That's because there is a set timeout function inside getmsg()

Comment: Check now I edited the code

Comment: Yeah so i am delaying that intentionally so that getmsg takes time and then it runs after which displaymsg should run. For ex: If i make an api call then it will take time but i want the display function to run only after the api call is finished. That is why we use callbacks and promises. If i'm not wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Add delay before resolve() while creating promise if you are mocking the api call delay.

Comment: Resolve will only hit after the api call is done be it a 200 success or any other failure

Comment: I am really confused about creating promises. Please let me know where i understood wrong. Accroding to me we create callbacks so that it does not gets executed at last in a callback. Like if we have getmsg and displaymsg then we want to call getmsg(callback){//inside here we get the msg and then call the callback ryt?